# Debian command-line cannot resolve host

Tags: linux, debian, hostname, hosts

I'm having an issue where my remote command-line cannot resolve the local hostname. It doesn't show as `user@localhost`, `user@ip` or any variant, but instead as `user@(none)`:

```
Using username "rogue".
rogue@<my-ip>'s password:
Linux (none) 3.13.7-x86_64-linode38 #1 SMP Tue Mar 25 12:59:48 EDT 2014 x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sun Apr 27 15:34:56 2014 from ---
rogue@(none):~$
```

Any proceeding commands cause this warning message:

```
rogue@(none):~$ sudo service nginx start
sudo: unable to resolve host (none)
[sudo] password for rogue:
```

Looking at my hosts and hostname files, I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary:

/etc/hostname

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       debian

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

What could potentially be wrong with my network configuration? If possible, I would like that it says `user@my.domain`, but I need `localhost` to still route correctly to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `/etc/hostname` is very wrong. 
It should be plain text of FQDN, like ***example.com*** or ***localhost***, instead of a similar copy of `/etc/hosts`

You may want to use command `hostname` to view and set hostname, `man` it

Comment: Can you provide a sample, as this is how it was set since being set up with my VPS provider.

Comment: @Rogue check https://library.linode.com/email/exim/send-only-mta-debian-6-squeeze#sph_set-the-hostname

Comment: @Rogue sorry, should be https://library.linode.com/getting-started#sph_setting-the-hostname

Comment: Well yes, I can read the `man` page for hostname command, but I'm talking about the hostname file, which you said is "very wrong"

Comment: @Rogue it can be "localhost", or "example.com", and that's all

Answer (score 0):

What about these commands?

```
hostname here.yourhost.name
sudo sed -i "s|localhost|localhost $(hostname)|g" /etc/hosts
```

adding hostname next to other, localhost names in /etc/hosts

Comment: The `g` flag is obviously superfluous; why would you want to add the same information multiple times?

Comment: because i have not found you showing an example of better way to do it

Comment: Uh, take out the `g` flag?